# Need an advice about comments

Tags: comments, comment-form, social-connect

I am searching a solution for wordpress comments. I like standart comments, I already styled it and made some additionaly functionality. But there is one that I can't find and don't know how to make it.
I need an ability for unregistered users to left comments using some social service, [image: like at blogspot]. So, I don't want to offer them ability to log-in using their social service, but only to comment.

UPD: I didn't know about such rule. So ok, how can I realize this functionality? I mean authorization with accounts from any social service only to post a comment?

Comment: Updated question. Can I rely on this topic or I need to make a new one?

Comment: The question is fine now as it no longer asks for a plugin, but it is a very broad question. Each of those services has their own API. Answering the question would mean writing a complicated plugin. You are best getting yourself started and asking a specific question about a specific problem.